# Specify API Path

Tags: angular

I am developing an application in angular js 2.0. For bundling I am using WebPack and in the WebPack I am defining an API path which is accessible throughout the application.

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env':{
  'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
  'API_URL': JSON.stringify('http://10.28.83.123/nb-legal/api/')
}
```

But the issue is When i prepare the distribution build, I can't change the API url after that. Is there a way by which after distribution if i want to change the api path then i can easily do that instead rebuild the application again.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Once this `API_URL` variable is defined in your bundle it can not be changed. `DefinePlugin` does not actually declare a variable for you, it just replaces all the occurrences of that variable with the value. For example, if you define `API_URL` with `'http://10.28.83.123/nb-legal/api/'` and your source code looks something like this

`var someURL = API_URL + "get_items"`

The code in your bundle produced by webpack will look like this

`var someURL = 'http://10.28.83.123/nb-legal/api/' + "get_items"`

So the best option for you is to create another global variable in your code, like

`window.API_URL = API_URL;`

And then you can modify that variable.